# iPhone App name rejection?

Tags: iphone

Has anyone had apple send back the app with a name change requirement? We submitted our app in Nov. and have been going back and forth with them, we corrected the items they asked us to fix which were both interface and memory driven, and they said nothing about the name. They have been testing our API a TON so we know they are doing something on it, but today we saw a app with our same name come out. The developer had it released from Apple back in Dec. and just didn't turn it on till now. Why would Apple not tell us to change that by now, has anyone else had issues with their names, and how do we submit a new name mid process. Our apps are totally different, so that isn't the problem.

Comment: Just for the purposes of clarification, is the problem:
1) Apple is asking you to change the name of your application
2) Now that there is another application with the same name as yours, you want to change the name of your application?

Answer (score 4):

When it comes to copyright infringement apple has immediately put us in touch with creators of other apps that use our name. They don't want to get involved in a legal battles, but they do facilitate the connection between all parties. You may consider changing your name to avoid any further delays, as apple can simply wait on an app that they think could become a copyright issue.